# Bypass router for remote desktop 

Tags: windows, remote, vnc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best Remote Desktop Application?](https://superuser.com/questions/1585/whats-the-best-remote-desktop-application)

My family is abroad and often I need to help them with computer stuff.

Is there a simple way to take control of their session (like with VNC or NetMeeting) but without changing the router configuration?

They are not very skilled users so asking to configure VNC server is too much. Someone told me there a program you can launch from a browser.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do such stuff is with programs like Teamviewer. You don't have to setup anything on the client side. But you must trust the producer of Teamviewer in a certain way because their servers are involved in the communication. So it's up to you...
There are alternatives like [cspace](http://cspace.in/) or pcvisit but I never tested them...

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend LogMeIn from www.logmein.com - basically you would create an account on their website, and then for the first time, you would need to be either at their computer or ask them to use teamviewer by giving you an id and password to be on their computer. Once you are on or at their computer, log into LogMein and add their computer to your account. Then whenever they need "support" just go to LogMeIn and log into their computer with no interaction needed from them. LogMeIn has a free service for personal/home use.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Fog Creek Copilot](https://www.copilot.com/) it's pretty much zero configuration.